# javascript & html: What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body> 
<script>
    var image1 = newImage();
    image1.src = "./SkinnersLogo.png";
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = image1;
</script>
<img id="d"> </img>
</body>
</html>
```

I have set the value of image 1, to a source. I have then tried to innerHTML this image, and then display it within an img tag. However, all I see is a blank screen on the HTML window. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I cannot spot any mistakes, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image tag is already there on the page you could simply assign the src attribute like below.

```
<img id="d"> </img>

<script>
    var source= "./SkinnersLogo.png";
    document.getElementById("d").src = source;
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You forgot the space between the `new` operator and the `Image` function name
2. You called `getElementById` [before the element existed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)
3. You tried to assign a DOM node (the return value of `new Image`) as if it were a string of HTML (which it isn't). Use `appendChild(your_node)` not `innerHTML = your_html`.

---

Learn how to use the developer tools in your browser. You would have received a number of error messages in the Console which could have helped you debug this yourself.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, silly me, however - after fixing all of that, still no luck.